# Undefined index: token Error

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-1.2

I am using the github repository code here: https://github.com/hunzinker/CakePHP-Auth-Forgot-Password

I have used the following function in my `UsersController.php`. I get the error Undefined index: token on the line that has a comment before it. What should I change?

```
/**
 * Allow user to reset password if $token is valid.
 * @return
 */
function reset_password_token($reset_password_token = null) {
    if (empty($this->data)) {
        $this->data = $this->User->findByResetPasswordToken($reset_password_token);

        if (!empty($this->data['User']['reset_password_token']) &&
            !empty($this->data['User']['token_created_at']) &&
            $this->__validToken($this->data['User']['token_created_at'])
        ) {
            $this->data['User']['id'] = null;
            $_SESSION['token'] = $reset_password_token;
        } else {
            $this->Session->setflash(
                'The password reset request has either expired or is invalid.'
            );
            $this->redirect('/users/login');
        }
    } else {
        //ERROR ON THE NEXT LINE HERE UNDEFINED INDEX: TOKEN
        if ($this->data['User']['reset_password_token'] != $_SESSION['token']) {
            $this->Session->setflash(
                'The password reset request has either expired or is invalid.'
            );
            $this->redirect('/users/login');
        }

        $user = $this->User->findByResetPasswordToken(
            $this->data['User']['reset_password_token']
        );
        $this->User->id = $user['User']['id'];

        if ($this->User->save($this->data, array('validate' => 'only'))) {
            $this->data['User']['reset_password_token'] =
                $this->data['User']['token_created_at'] = null;

            if ($this->User->save($this->data) &&
                $this->__sendPasswordChangedEmail($user['User']['id'])
            ) {
                unset($_SESSION['token']);
                $this->Session->setflash(
                    'Your password was changed successfully. Please login to continue.'
                );
                $this->redirect('/users/login');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure that **$_SESSION** contains this index, so you should update it like this in order to be sure it exists:

By this:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['token']) || $this->data['User']['reset_password_token'] != $_SESSION['token']) {
    $this->Session->setflash(
        'The password reset request has either expired or is invalid.'
    );
    $this->redirect('/users/login');
}
```

Comment: When I use public $actsAs = array('Acl' => array('type' => 'requester')); in my User.php model I get the following error: Warning (512): Callback parentNode() not defined in User [CORE/Cake/Model/Behavior/AclBehavior.php, line 65] Is Acl requester necessary to make this work? I am using CakePHP version 2.2.2.

Comment: I changed $this->User->data to $this->request->data and I changed $html->link to $this->Html->link. What else do I need to change in order to upgrade to version 2?

Comment: Thanks to SamHecquet.

Comment: I also changed $this->redirect('/users/login'); to $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users','action' => 'login'));

Comment: How does the controller find the vendor shell file named password_reset_token.php?